# Checkerboard with tables in HTML?

Tags: html, css

Edit: please keep in mind that I know next to nothing aboutJavaScript, CSS etc. and have had to find these things on my own. I started just a couple hours ago and don't know most of the things in the replies. Sorry.

I have to make a 50 x 50 checkerboard using ONLY html and ONLY tables. I've obviously given up on this maniacal request and tried using some CSS (even though my teacher hasn't taught us yet) but I can't get it to work. How should I go about this? I've tried doing it like this, but my teacher started teaching us html only a couple months ago (we're EXTREMELY late on the program) and it's really bad.

(At the bottom is what I wrote into the CSS file)

`code`

```
<head>
    <title> Compito scacchiera tabelle </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="colore.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        var i = 0;
        for(i=0; i<=50; i++){
            <tr>
                for(i=0; i<=50; i++){
                    if(i % 2 == 0){
                        <td id="nero;"> </td>
                    }
                    else{
                        <td> </td>
                    }
                
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

The CSS file:

```
#nero {
background-color: black;
color: black;
}
```

Comment: Did you forget post your CSS file? Also, this is neather valid javascript nor HTML code. Please use snippet button to post code.

Comment: `id` at all times **must be unique**. https://www.w3schools.com/hTML/html_id.asp Use `class` instead.

Comment: You cannot just mix JavaScript and HTML. That's a ReactJS thing.

Comment: Are you supposed to be using Javascript or only HTML?

Comment: In javascript (which you are using to generate HTML) you can't simply insert HTML code inside of it, you must use variables to store/generate HTML code and than insert it into HTML page. (in PHP you could do something like this, but not in JS).

Answer (score 1):

Use [CSS `:nth-child(odd / even)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

```js
const size = 50;

const checkers = Array.from(Array(size)).reduce((r) => {
  r += `<tr>${"<td></td>".repeat(size)}</tr>`;
  return r;
}, "");

document.querySelector("#scacchiera").innerHTML = checkers;
```

```css
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
td {width: 5px; height: 5px;}

tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even),
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd){
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<table id="scacchiera"></table>
```

Comment: Wow, this is really incredible. Thank you. Unfortunately this includes stuff that my teacher has yet to show us and when we do that he gets mad and marks that homework as not completed. Again thanks, and sorry.

Comment: @Vasil____ your teacher should know that you are **students** first and foremost. That does not means that your knowledge should stop where your teacher's teaching reaches. And those couple of lines of JS and CSS... you can google what each method does. And eventually end up smarter than your teacher.

Answer (score 0):

First, construct your HTML in a string, adding on the new bits as you go

Next, you will need to test your inner loop to see if it should begin with white or black

Finally, do not use the same var in each for loop, or it will terminate the outer for loop when the inner for loop is finished.  (i === i  === 8).

```js
out = '<table>';
var i=0, j=0;
for (j = 0; j <= 8; j++) { 
  out += '<tr>';
    if (j % 2 == 0){
      for (i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) { 
          out += '<td style="height:15px;width:15px;background:black;"> </td>';
        } else {
          out += '<td style="height:15px;width:15px;background:palegoldenrod;"> </td>';
        }
      }
    } else {
      for (i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) { 
          out += '<td style="height:15px;width:15px;background:palegoldenrod;"> </td>';
        } else {
          out += '<td style="height:15px;width:15px;background:black;"> </td>';
        }
      }
    }
    out += '</tr>';
}
out += '</table>';
document.body.innerHTML = out;
```

Comment: Constructing HTML with text is rather error prone, and I, for one, would also consider it not too readable. Why not use `appendChild` or one of the other methods for tables?

Comment: @amn even though it's not the most optimal or easy to read example, it still valid...

Comment: Because I prefer it.  I use both methods, but - as a personal preference - I generally go with strings.  I take it your personal preference is different - vive la difference.  Also, for a beginner, it removes one more layer of complexity -- and when I was a beginner, I found that such small adjustments to code examples helped me to understand.

Comment: I upvoted your comment for the believable explanation, even in my disagreement.

Answer (score 0):

1. In javascript you can't just inject HTML as plain text, you must use
   variable to store html as string and when it's finished generating
   insert it into HTML page.
2. When have a `for` loop inside another `for` loop you must use unique
   variable names, otherwise outer loop will be canceled by the inner loop.
3. Elements IDs must be unique, so in this case you should use `class` instead.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
td {
  min-width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: silver;
}

.nero {
  background-color: black;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="board"></table>
    <script>
var html = ""; //generated HTML will be stored here
var num = 10; //number of boxes per row/column
for (var y = 0; y <= num; y++) //rows loop
{
  html += '<tr>'; //add a row
  for (var x = 0; x <= num; x++) //columns loop
  {
    if ((y + x) % 2 == 0) //to alternate color between each row, we use position of current row + column
    {
      html += '<td class="nero"></td>'; //using class instead of ID
    }
    else
    {
      html += '<td></td>'
    }

  }
  html += '</tr>'
}

document.getElementById("board").innerHTML = html; //insert generated html into table
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this assignment should be done using only HTML you should just copy and paste rows many times it won't take you that long.

That beign said, first of all you can't just embed HTML in your Javascript like that, you should you probably be using DOM methods, also I see that you are using an id for your `td` elements, you shouldn't be using an id in multiple elements you should be using a class instead.

You can go to [freeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn) and learn about this concepts :).

Here is a working example of how I did it using the DOM:

```js
const table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  table.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
  const row = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[i];

  for(let j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
    row.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));

    if((i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0) || (i % 2 == 1 && j % 2 == 1)) {
      const cell = row.getElementsByTagName('td')[j];
      cell.className = 'nero';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.nero {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<table>
</table>
```